# How to pass the pointer values from a separate function back to main using a structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define G 9.81
```

//structure bring used is called USER_INPUT

```
typedef struct
{
    double weight;
    double drag;
    double time;

} USER_INPUT;

void getInput(USER_INPUT *); //function prototype - which i think works

void main()

{
    USER_INPUT input;
    getInput(&input);
```

//This is where the inputted values should show up but it won't return anything

```
    printf("Weight = ", input.weight);
    printf("Drag = ", input.drag);
    printf("Time =", input.drag);


}
```

//Separate function where i get the inputs from user. it works but value are not passed back to main

```
void getInput (USER_INPUT *inpPtr)
{
    printf("Please enter the weight:");
    scanf("%lf", &inpPtr->weight);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter the drag:");
    scanf("%lf", &inpPtr->drag);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter the time:");
    scanf("%lf", &inpPtr->time);
    fflush(stdin);
    return(0); //<- idk if this is right either

}
```

Comment: It is not correct, you are not allowed to return a value if the return type is `void`. Your problem is that your `printf`s are not correct. http://ideone.com/f3BqOC

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you describe can be attributed to the fact that you left the format specifiers out of your `printf()` statements. Also, you attempt to display `.drag` twice:

```
printf("Weight = %g\n", input.weight);
printf("Drag = %g\n", input.drag);
printf("Time = %g\n", input.time);
```

The function `getInput()` does not pass values back to `main()` (it has a return type of `void`, after all!), but it modifies the values stored in the fields of the `USER_INPUT` struct `input` which exists in the scope of `main()`.

There are some other issues here. The `main()` function always returns an `int`, and you should declare it like this:

```
int main(void){}
```

Alternatively, if you are using command-line arguments, you can do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}
```

or:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){}
```

Flushing an input stream is undefined behavior, although it works on some systems. For portability it is best not to do this. You can use something like:

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
    continue;
```

to discard unwanted characters in the input stream after a call to `scanf()`.

Finally, a function with return type `void` does not need a `return` statement, although some people like to use `return ;` to make the return explicit. But, returning an `int` value from such a function is certainly wrong.